# How to escape the # character in csvreader

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I'm following this [csvsimple documentation](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf) and I've come across an issue with my csv file having a reserved character: **#** and I've tried escaping it with a `blackslash(\)` and I've tried appending `[respect sharp]` to `\csvreader` (since you can escape the underscore by doing that) but to no avail.  I know you can use [respect sharp] with `\csvautotabular`, but I can't seem to find out how to do this with csvreader

This is my code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|c|}\hline%
   & Person & Matr.~No.\\\hline\hline
   \csvreader[tabular=|r|l|l|, table head=\hline, table foot=\hline]%
   {csv/scientists.csv}{name=\name,description=\desc}%
   {\thecsvrow & \name & \desc}%
\end{tabular}
```

This is my csv code:

```
name, description
Locking, {Priced standard #2.  Priced outside #1.}
```

Getting an `Illegal parameter number in definition of \csv@col@body` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `respect sharp` key is indeed the correct key to use. Your code doesn't really compile to what I think you want (it's helpful for future question to embed the code into a complete compilable document that people can play with.)

Here's a version of the code you posted. As you can see, both `csvautotabular` and `csvreader` allow the same `respect sharp` option. I removed the `tabular` specification inside the `csvreader` command, since you don't really want a table within a table I don't think.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
name, description
Locking,{Priced standard #2.  Priced outside #1.}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular[respect sharp]{\jobname.csv}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|r|l|c|}
   \hline%
   & Person & Matr.~No.\\\hline\hline
   \csvreader[ table head=\hline, table foot=\hline, respect sharp]%
   {\jobname.csv}{name=\name,description=\desc}%
   {\thecsvrow & \name & \desc}
   \\\hline%
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]